# Edit post or leave alone or delete entirely?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, deleted-questions

Ok, I know that the question "Should I delete my post" has been asked here a thousand times. And this one probably isn't new either, but I've been unable to find a definitive consensus on what I should do when my question is wrong, but another similar question is unanswered.

Yesterday, I asked a question about batch files leaving windows open after a certain program runs.
Long story short, I later learned that the entire premise for my question was wrong. What is the SOP here? Should I delete it and ask another very similar but distinct question, should I edit the original, should I leave the question open and post another, or should I post an answer explaining why my premise was wrong? I am still curious and I know that my original question will never get an answer in its current form.

For context, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539214/batch-call-causes-script-execution-to-hang-due-to-cd-command-within-call) is the original question. It has 10 views, 1 comment and no answers. I really meant to ask if anyone knew why the popup window does not close after I call `start scons` from the terminal, so 90% of the context is not necessary now that I know that this behavior is the root of my problem.

Comment: Posting an answer that explains why the question is wrong would not be an answer; don't post answers which are not answers. The question has no existing answers currently, so there is little harm in editing it. The general idea is that edits to a question should not invalidate good answers, but other than that it is still *your* question so have at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing question to clarify what you actually want to know is fine.

If it means you have to significantly alter the post - consider if there are existing answers that actually answer original question. If there are and your edit will invalidate them - ask new question instead. Note that question may still be on-topic and of reasonable quality even if you've asked something completely different from what you intended to.

Another option is simply delete the post at least till you figure out what you actually wanted to ask and confirmed that it is actually on-topic. To my knowledge there is no penalty for deleting posts *that do not have answers*.

Note that batch file questions are often borderline off-topic for SO. You may want to spend some extra time researching new version of the question and see if it scoped to just "tools primary used for programming" (SO is fine for those) or more generic (you'd better off asking on SuperUser.com)